# Why is the declaration of std::unique_ptr valid with an abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, unique-ptr

for example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class abstract_class
{
public:
    abstract_class() = default;
    ~abstract_class() = default;
    virtual void read() = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<abstract_class> x;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << "!\n";
}
```

I thought an Abstract Class had these Restrictions 
Abstract classes can't be used for: 
Variables or member data 
**Argument types** <---------
Function return types 
Types of explicit conversions

In the above code we are using the abstract class as a template argument so why isnt this an error.

Comment: You're not using it as an argument type.

Comment: You're creating a unique **pointer** to the abstract class object and not an object of the abstract class itself. Just imagine why you can also write: `abstract_class *ptr;` without any error.

Comment: In C++ "argument types" don't include template arguments.

Comment: Argument types is for `void foo(abstract_class var)`. it is not for `my_class<T>`.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is a pointer - just smart. So it is valid to have `std::unique_ptr<bastrac_class>` same as `abstract_class*` is valid too. This is the main feature of polymorphism. So please read chapter about polymorphism more carefully.

Comment: They mean function argument types, not template argument types.

Comment: It is an argument to the template, but `abstract_class` is not the *type* of the argument, it *is*  the argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first, the *argument types* that you've mentioned in your question is for **function call arguments** and not for **template arguments**.

---

> why isnt this an error.

Because you're creating a unique **pointer** to the abstract class object and not an object of the abstract class itself. That is, *creating a pointer(whether unique or not) to a abstract class type is allowed.*

For example, just think that you can also write the following without any error:

```
abstract_class *ptr; //this also works for the same reason
```